# Given $f:A\to B\times C$ and $g:A\to C$, how to indicate that $g(a)=c$ coincides with the second element of the pair $f(a)=(b,c)\forall a\in A$?

Tags: functions, notation

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be arbitrary sets with elements $a\in A$, $b\in B$ and $c\in C$. Further, let $f:A\to B\times C$ be a function, and let $g:A\to B$ be another function that *coincides with the corestriction of $f$ to $C$ for all elements $a\in A$*. I don’t know how to express the idea in italics in formal terms. I would like to write something like $g(a)=f(a)$, but this notation is incorrect because $g(a)=c$ and $f(a)=(b,c)$. Specifically, I want to say that $g(a)=c$ always coincides with the second element of the pair $f(a)=(b,c)$ for all $a\in A$.

**Can anybody help me express this idea formally? Is there any good notation for that?**

Comment: Let $\pi_2: B \times C \to C \ (b,c) \mapsto c$. Then the required condition is "$g = \pi_2 \circ f$"

Comment: I see how the notation you propose would work. Unfortunately, this is for an oral presentation at a conference and I’m looking for the simplest possible notation. I think I may end up using custom notation along a verbal explanation of my notation.

Comment: Bespoke notation for a speech should be fine, though that will depend heavily on the content of your speech so will be hard to advise you on what notation to pick. I will add that the $\pi_2$ function I have given you is idiomatic mathematics in the sense of  [projection functions from category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)). However This conceptualisation or notation will only be useful if your audience is familiar with the concept

Comment: For a function $f : A \to B \times C$ we have two *component/coordinate* functions $f_1 : A \to B$ and $f_2 : A \to C$ such that $f(a) = (f_1(a),f_2(a))$ for all $a \in A$. This is how every function into a product (the codomain is a product) sees. Thus, you can say that $g$ is the *second component function* of $f$, or something like that.